# how to server over http and https with one installation

Tags: configuration, http, https, customization, proxy

is there an easy way to set up a single wordpress intallation to serve its pages both over http and https?

I have an http based website, and I have some pages that I would like to make accessible as facebook pages too. But facebook requires https, and I would prefer to stay with https for normal requests.

Do you know a way to share the same page over both protocols? I'm running my wordpress on a webfaction account.

Akasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup the SSL certificate for your domain on your web server, your WordPress site will immediately be accessible via `http / https` connections without any extra configuration.

Any configuration is required when you want your website or its backend (`wp-admin` / `wp-login.php`) to load ONLY via SSL (HTTPS).

But there's at least one thing you should take care of:

- Make sure your canonical URLs are either HTTP or HTTPS only (whichever you want to show up in search results). [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) has an option to enforce this. Not sure, but [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin *may be* of some help.